# How to use lvconvert with two disks for mirroring? - Insufficient suitable allocatable extents

Tags: lvm

On a RHEL 5 I have to create an LVM mirror from multipath disks. 
There are enough free extents, but - on two disks, because the VG was made out of 4 disks.

```
[root@SERVER ~]# pvs -v --segments | head -1
    Scanning for physical volume names
  PV                              VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start SSize  LV                 Start Type   PE Ranges                              
[root@SERVER ~]# pvs -v --segments | grep archivvg6
    Scanning for physical volume names
  /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc1     archivvg6 lvm2 a--   32.00G  32.00G     0   8191                        0 free                                          
  /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc2     archivvg6 lvm2 a--   32.00G      0      0   8191 orau011archlv          0 linear /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc2:0-8190     
  /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc1      archivvg6 lvm2 a--    8.00G   8.00G     0   2047                        0 free                                          
  /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc2      archivvg6 lvm2 a--    8.00G      0      0   2047 orau011archlv       8191 linear /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc2:0-2046      
[root@SERVER ~]# lvs | grep archivvg6
  orau011archlv      archivvg6 -wi-ao  39.99G                                      
[root@SERVER ~]# lvconvert --mirrorlog mirrored -m 1 archivvg6/orau011archlv /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc1 /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc1
  Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 10238 more required
  Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
[root@SERVER ~]# 
[root@SERVER ~]# lvconvert --mirrorlog mirrored -m 1 archivvg6/orau011archlv /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc1
  Insufficient free space: 10238 extents needed, but only 8191 available
  Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

**Question**: how can I use "lvconvert" command to use the two disks?

**UPDATE:** Would "--alloc anywhere" help? update: no..:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# lvconvert -i 5 --alloc anywhere --mirrorlog mirrored -m 1 archivvg6/orau011archlv /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc1 /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc1
  Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 2 more required
  Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

Comment: You need to free up more extents.  Mirroring takes more space than a single copy.

Comment: if you add the free on the two disks, then you get exactly the "10238 extents needed". So the problem could be that it doesn't recognizes that I want 2 disk for mirroring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) there was a syntax error, this is the GOOD one:

```
lvconvert -v -m 1 --mirrorlog mirrored /dev/archivvg6/orau011archlv /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc1 /dev/mpath/orau11db6_32gcc2 /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc1 /dev/mpath/orau11db6_8gcc2
```

CC1 CC2 CC1 CC2

but the man page doesn't really speaks about this.. :)

2) 1 free PE is needed per PV! So decrease the FS, then LV size to free up 4 MByte..